# Not able to position <button> inside a <li>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

So I basically want to do a list, each li containing an anchor and a dropdown menu (using bootstrap). The li are contained into a div, itself contained into a ul. I successfully aligned the anchors on the left, and I would like to do the same thing for the dropdowns on the right, but it's not working. Here's the result, each element with a border to visualize its behaviour.

[image]

Here's the html...

```
<ul>
    <li class="list_items"><a href="data/'.$file.'" download target="_blank">'.$location.'</a> 
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
                More info <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
              <!-- items of the dropdown menu -->
            </ul>
        </div> 
    </li>

    <!-- repeat... -->
</ul>
```

... and the css

```
ul
{
    display: inline-block;  
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right:0;
    vertical-align: top;
    width:240px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    text-align: justify;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#list_box // div containing the whole list
{
    border-right: 2px solid #b2dba1;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #b2dba1;
    border-left: 2px solid #b2dba1;
    border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
    width: 230px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    background: rgba(206,232,196,0.7);
    padding-right:0;
}

.list_items // all the <li>
{
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px dashed red;
}

ul .list_items .dropdown button
{
    position: relative;
    right: 2px;
    margin-right: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.dropdown // div containing the button
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

What else could be done to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for this?

Comment: Humm, i've never done that. And my code is called dynamically via ajax :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the standard bootstrap class 'pull-right' at the dropdown div.

Then it will look like this:
`<div class="dropdown pull-right">`

I think that should do the trick.

Comment: Problem is that the dropdown button is higher then the text.

You can prevent this kind of problems by adding the class 'row' to the list_items li.

I've made a jsfiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/58eDK/1/

Comment: Ok wow, it seems almost perfect, will confirm in few minutes!

Comment: Thanks a lot Skeevs, it works, I just have to position the anchors a little bit lower to align them with the buttons!